# error[E0277]: the trait bound `Vec<TokenStream2>: ToTokens` is not satisfied

Tags: rust

I ran into this error and thought my very hacky workaround might be of use to someone.

Suppose I have some code [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=61f1c3831e436e9c86e53748884c63d3) which looks like this:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate quote;
extern crate syn;
extern crate proc_macro2; // 1.0.24

fn main() {
    let x = vec![
        quote! {let x = 1;},
        quote! {let x = 2;}
    ];
    println!("{:#?}", quote! {
        #x
    });
}
```

This doesn't compile.

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Vec<TokenStream2>: ToTokens` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:11:23
   |
11 |       println!("{:#?}", quote! {
   |  _______________________^
12 | |         #x
13 | |     });
   | |_____^ the trait `ToTokens` is not implemented for `Vec<TokenStream2>`
   |
   = note: required by `to_tokens`
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: aborting due to previous error
```

How do I use `quote!` to concatenate a `Vec<proc_macro2::TokenStream>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason, `quote::ToTokens` isn't implemented for `proc_macro2::TokenStream`.

**New answer**

This is achievable using the `quote!` macro's syntax:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate quote;
extern crate syn;
extern crate proc_macro2; // 1.0.24

fn main() {
    let x = vec![
        quote! {let x = 1;},
        quote! {let x = 2;}
    ];
    println!("{:#?}", quote! {
        #(#x)*
    });
}
```

**Old answer**

To fix this, one possible workaround is to use `fold` [(playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=af93087fdee5a4d908561eaf9ac87729).

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate quote;
extern crate syn;
extern crate proc_macro2; // 1.0.24

fn main() {
    let x = vec![
        quote! {let x = 1;},
        quote! {let x = 2;}
    ].iter().fold(quote! {}, |acc, new| quote! {#acc #new});
    println!("{:#?}", quote! {
        #x
    });
}
```

This now compiles, producing the expected output:

```
TokenStream [
    Ident {
        sym: let,
    },
    Ident {
        sym: x,
    },
    Punct {
        char: '=',
        spacing: Alone,
    },
    Literal {
        lit: 1,
        span: bytes(1..2),
    },
    Punct {
        char: ';',
        spacing: Alone,
    },
    Ident {
        sym: let,
    },
    Ident {
        sym: x,
    },
    Punct {
        char: '=',
        spacing: Alone,
    },
    Literal {
        lit: 2,
        span: bytes(3..4),
    },
    Punct {
        char: ';',
        spacing: Alone,
    },
]
```